# How do I create a find to search and array of arrays

Tags: meteor

I have created a seed for my meteor app with the following code.

```
if (Years.find().count() === 0) {
    for (y = 1905; y < 2015; y++ ) {
        Years.insert({
            year: y
        }); 
    }
}
```

I then want to reference the _id or year field in find statements within my app.

What I have seen is that the seed creates what seems to me to be an array of arrays

I have tried to run a query that look like this.

```
Years.find().fetch()
```

And this returned the array of arrays

```
Years.find().fetch();
 Array[110]
  [0 … 99]
    0: Object
     _id: "hPXZuc54irJQ78mQ5"
     year: 1905
     __proto__: Object
    1: Object
     _id: "Z7nuSCRA8W7nn9j92"
     year: 1906
     __proto__: Object
  [100 … 109]
  length: 110
```

I then tried to use $elemMatch from searching stackoverflow.

```
Years.find({year: {$elemMatch:{ year: "1988" } } });
```

And this is what I got back

```
LocalCollection.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, _selectorId: undefined, matcher: Minimongo.Matcher, skip: undefined…}
_selectorId: undefined
_transform: null
collection: LocalCollection
  _docs: LocalCollection._IdMap
    _idParse: function (id) {  // 1079                                                             
   _idStringify: function (id) {  // 1054
   _map: Object
     2BiEQnaFo37MfXgZo: Object
     2LXuNkpH3uq27Wobw: Object
```

Is there a better way to seed perhaps? or do I need to change the way I query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection is actually made of a document per year.

the `.fetch()` makes an array of all the documents

you've also inserted your years as numbers, so you need to query with a number

your elemmatch query doesn't really make sense, its trying to query the "year" array in each document, which doesn't exist.  a year is a number, not an array by the way you have defined it.

so you can just do

```
Years.findOne({year: 1988})
```

To see what's going on with mongo ( where the data is stored) go to your mongo console

in your project folder

```
meteor mongo
```

then you can do

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.years.find().pretty()
```

and you should see a bunch of documents like :-

```
{ "year" : 1905, "_id" : "XEyPJnQeFpzxwWnWT" }
{ "year" : 1906, "_id" : "eT6Ctz5yQpZ5FpDuE" }
{ "year" : 1907, "_id" : "7jwaxumxT73X9fAK2" }
{ "year" : 1908, "_id" : "aoMJhnNBaMBv2u9ip" }
{ "year" : 1909, "_id" : "Doyta3rnXE5NvwFTY" }
{ "year" : 1910, "_id" : "uHxAsxcyi9GNYeTbN" }
{ "year" : 1911, "_id" : "BG7AmXxdMRjDLG7cp" }
```

Comment: Fantastic!!!! this helped me with my issue in seeding and also understanding how this will work when you want to translate year.id to the actual year.